# How to secure Web API without individual logins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an api that calculates some math based on inputs and returns the result.

I have multiple asp.net mvc sites that have a javascript graph which updates the graph according to user input / ajax calls from api

I want the sites and graph pages to be open access. People should be able to view/update the graphs without having to login.

However, I don't want people to be able to directly plug-in to my api and use it for themselves. The only time someone sees the output of the api should be through my own sites.

Is this possible?

I've been reading through https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io and perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but there's no way to do it without exposing the access token to javascript?

I can use C#/MVC to get the access token which keeps username/password from being exposed:

```
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");
var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api1");
```

But then for the javascript graph to make api calls, it needs to know that token.

Once I've exposed the token to javascript, what's to stop someone getting that token and using it to call the api? And even if the token expires, can't they just automate grabbing a new token from my sites to use in their api calls again?

If there's any benefit, I could move all the sites/api to the same server. Perhaps IP restriction could be used, but then again, couldn't someone send requests with a spoofed IP address to get around that?

Comment: CORS can help you here. You can just set the CORS domain to yours one and then only the request from specific domain will be entertained. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar I think that's just Browser/Client security though. From your link it says "Specifically, the browser disallows the request. Even if the server returns a successful response, the browser does not make the response available to the client application". So someone could still easily write a C# app to use the api, and CORS won't block that (I just tried it myself and I could access api from C#, even though I couldnt from jquery/ajax)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Only browsers adheres the CORS parameters. Other clients like C# would still be able to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked with the [AllowAnonymous] attribute. If you put this attribute on your "Action" that you want to be open access, then anyone can access the method without login. 
If you want to allow access to a specific site/source, then please add this in your web.config file inside 
`<system.webServer></system.webServer>.`

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
```

See here * means you are allowing everyone. You can place your site address instead of * that only you want to access your api.

Let me know is that what you want or anything else.

Comment: @OP is looking for securing the anonymous access such that only request from specific site needs to be entertained and not for public. So token based authentication and AllowAnonumous doesn't solves that purpose as anyone can get the token and use the API and for AllowAnonymous it'd open the API for public use.

Comment: Could not understand why down voted ?? Check my update answer.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin / Cors only works on a browser though right? I just made an empty WebApp to connect to a WebApi with Access-Control-Allow-Orgin = "http://NotMyWebApp". I couldn't access the data from jquery/ajax, but in my controller I did httpclient.GetAsync and it returned the api values no problem

Comment: @mejobloggs Currently I'm working on a project where we have implemented "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and we are able to get/post data from our webApp project jquery/ajax code. You need to specify "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in your API project web.config file and there you need to specify your web project URL in place of *.

Answer (score 0):

When your site renders your page, include an encrypted json token in the page. The token will include a timestamp. When your page calls your api, include the token. Your service decrypts the token, validates the timestamp is less that NN minutes. If either of these fail, no business.

This way only your site will know how to create the correct token required to call your api. Tokens can not be replayed if the timestamp age is short enough.

You can get creative as to the structure/content of the token and how you encrypt, AES is a good choice.

Comment: How is this different to a normal token with short expiration? Someone could still grab the encrypted token from the JavaScript page and use it to call the api

Comment: The timestamp expires the token. When the token is received, check the timestamp, if older than NN minutes, deny service.